# Results list text input filter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, list, filter

I have a list of contacts, pulled from a MySQL database and displayed using PHP/HTML/CSS etc.

I'm looking to create a filter so as the user types in a textbox it filters the contact list down to those that match the inputted text.  Something like this http://kilianvalkhof.com/uploads/listfilter/

Now, that's fine for a shorter fixed list.  What would be the best approach to do the same sort of thing, but for a contacts list of around the 10,000 mark, and results per page of 0, 50, or 100.

I could use jQuery DIV requery/reload on keyup - it would work, I just wanted to know if there is a more efficient way of doing it? The perfect working example is Apple iCloud website Contacts Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of functionality look into AngularJS.

Comment: Thanks, I just found the perfect tutorial here  http://www.angularcode.com/angularjs-datagrid-paging-sorting-filter-using-php-and-mysql/